# How do I add a general Google Search bar into an HTML page in a Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have made a New Tab Google Chrome extension and I am currently writing the HTML code. However, I need to add a Google Search bar to the code. How do I do that not using Google Custom Search, but just the general searching?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT:** The following example doesn't work. Check the [codepen](https://codepen.io/kitanga/pen/GRyJEBj) here

You can create your own form or input tag and have it some javascript redirect the user to the Google page with the search query

```html
<form id=search action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">
  <input type="search" name="q" />
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

The html code above will show the google webpage with the search results.

Comment: You know if you are going to just dislike a post at least have the decency to share why the code is wrong